# Trying to add scroll event listener on window, but getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to add the bottom shadow to the search bar on scroll in react js. it is working well until I go on the second page of my app.

When I am trying to go on the second page, it showing

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Not working code :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineSearch } from "react-icons/ai";

const SearchBar = ({ totalPrograms, programs, setPrograms }) => {

    const handleScroll = () => {
        if(window.scrollY) {
            document.getElementById('sb-header').classList.add('h-shadow');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('sb-header').classList.remove('h-shadow');
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)};
    },[]);

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const searchProgramName = document.getElementById('search').value;
        
        if(searchProgramName) {
            setPrograms(
                programs.filter(program => 
                    program.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchProgramName)
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            handleClick();
        }
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        const allPhase = document.getElementsByName('phase');
        const checkedPhaseValue = [];

        allPhase.forEach(phase => {
            if(phase.checked) {
                checkedPhaseValue.push(phase.value);
            }
        });

        setPrograms(checkedPhaseValue.length ?
            totalPrograms.filter(
                program => checkedPhaseValue.includes(program.phase.toLowerCase())
            )
            : totalPrograms
        );
    }

    return (
        <header id='sb-header' className="container header-sb"> 
            <form className="container container-center" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="type-search">
                    <AiOutlineSearch className="icon"/>
                    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="search by program name"/>
                </div>
                <div className="checkbox-container">
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="open_application" value="application_open"/>
                        <label htmlFor="open_application">Open Application</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="application_in_review" value="application_review"/>
                        <label htmlFor="application_in_review">Application in Review</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="in_progress" value="in_progress"/>
                        <label htmlFor="in_progress">in Progress</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="completed" value="completed"/>
                        <label htmlFor="completed">Completed</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </header>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

On the second page, I am going by clicking on the Details button. Code for that :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { FaAngleDoubleRight } from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as ROUTES from '../Constants/routes';

const ProgramCards = ({ program }) => {
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
                <h1 className="p-name">{program.name}</h1>
            </div>

            <div className="card-body">
                <h3 className="p-category">{program.category}</h3>
                <small className="p-phase">{(program.phase).replace('_', ' ')}</small>
                <p className="p-description">{program.shortDescription}</p>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div className="date-duration">
                    <small className="p-date">Start Date: {program.startDate}</small>
                    <small className="p-duration">Duration: {program.duration}</small>
                </div>
                <Link to={ROUTES.PROGRAM_DETAILS}>
                    <button className="card-button">
                        Details <FaAngleDoubleRight className="icon angled-icon" />
                    </button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProgramCards;
```

My question is, why it is not working?

After this, I tried a different approach. And it is working well.

Working code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AiOutlineSearch } from "react-icons/ai";

const SearchBar = ({ totalPrograms, programs, setPrograms }) => {

    const [ scrolled, setScrolled ] = useState(false);

    const handleScroll = () => {
        if(window.scrollY > 10) {
            setScrolled(true);
        }
        else {
            setScrolled(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

        return () => {window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)};
    },[]);

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const searchProgramName = document.getElementById('search').value;
        
        if(searchProgramName) {
            setPrograms(
                programs.filter(program => 
                    program.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchProgramName)
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            handleClick();
        }
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        const allPhase = document.getElementsByName('phase');
        const checkedPhaseValue = [];

        allPhase.forEach(phase => {
            if(phase.checked) {
                checkedPhaseValue.push(phase.value);
            }
        });

        setPrograms(checkedPhaseValue.length ?
            totalPrograms.filter(
                program => checkedPhaseValue.includes(program.phase.toLowerCase())
            )
            : totalPrograms
        );
    }

    return (
        <header className={`container header-sb ${scrolled && 'h-shadow'}`}>
            <form className="container container-center" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="type-search">
                    <AiOutlineSearch className="icon"/>
                    <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="search by program name"/>
                </div>
                <div className="checkbox-container">
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="open_application" value="application_open"/>
                        <label htmlFor="open_application">Open Application</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="application_in_review" value="application_review"/>
                        <label htmlFor="application_in_review">Application in Review</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="in_progress" value="in_progress"/>
                        <label htmlFor="in_progress">in Progress</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="d-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick={handleClick} name="phase" id="completed" value="completed"/>
                        <label htmlFor="completed">Completed</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </header>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is the better and the react way to do it. It is generally discouraged to query the DOM managed by react yourself. Use ref's if you need the DOM node.

The first example is not working because `handleScroll` will be recreated every time the component re-renders. Therefore removing the listener will not remove the original listener as the function referenced by `handleScroll` has changed.

Therefore when your component unmounts the listener will not be removed correctly but react will remove the DOM node. Next time you scroll the handler will still be called but the node you are trying to query isn't there anymore.

You have to create the listener inside of `useEffect` so that your `removeEventListener` references the correct function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => setScrolled(window.scrollY > 10);

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
},[]);
```

Alternatively you could use `useRef` to create a stable reference to you listener function.

Comment: You said that in the first example, `handle scroll` will be recreated every time when the components re-renders. But the component will not render only one time? And the cleanup calls before re-rendering. So the remove listener should not remove the correct callback function?